# IntegrityError:duplicate key value violates unique constraint "login_account_userprofile_user_id_key"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

IntegrityError comes when user uploading the profile pic, on `form.save()` it gives error, here is the code (" ` " it is uses for formality at last of line)

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)`
    image = models.FileField(upload_to ="profile_image")`
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username`
```

## forms.py

```
class ProfilePicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("image",)`
```

## view.py

```
def profile_pic(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = ProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user =request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/login/profile')
    else:
        args = {'form': ProfilePicForm()}
        return render(request, 'login_account/profile_pic.html',args)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try the following:

```
user = UserProfile(user=request.user)
form = ProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: yeah, thanks it resolves that error but now it gives a different error "Keyerror `KeyError at /login/profile_pic/

u'password' `   in `form.is_valid()`

Comment: I believe you do not have a landing page for user login? You're somewhere trying to access `password` in a dictionary.